# NODEJS dns.lookup

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a site's name from terminal and do a dnslookup to print its IP on screen , but the following code is throwing an error for some reason , here is the code

```
process.stdout.write('Enter the website name:<www.sitename.com>: ');
process.stdin.resume();
var dns = require('dns');
process.stdin.on('data',function(site) {


var lookup = site.toString('utf-8');
console.log(lookup);
dns.lookup(lookup,function(err,ip) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(ip);
       });

});
```

The error is 
if (err) throw err;
               ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:123:16)

Why isnt the code working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the **data** on *stdin* gives you the host with a trailing carriage return. This trailing CR leads to the getaddrinfo ENOENT exception.

modify your code with

```
var lookup = site.toString('utf-8').trim();
```